# MySQL server often randomly disconnected

Tags: mysql

On my web server (OVH/Ubuntu) I have 2 or 3 times a month a mysql interruption, that is all my data are not loaded. I have indeed this following error.

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Thus, I have to connect to my web server via ssh and type this to restart mysql and get my data loaded on my websites(PHP) :

```
service mysql restart
```

It is really annoying because that happens frequently and hence my websites do not work properly and I must check regularly to see if I need to restart mysql.

What happens ? How can I correct this situation ? So that MySQL can always be connected ...

Answer (score 1):

Does a simple start work as well as restart (`service mysql start`) - if so that would imply that mysql has fallen over rather then just stopped responding.

In which case, after an unplanned stop do you see anything in the log files such as mySQL's error log ([see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-log.html) or your operating system's logs (in `/var/log` - `daemon.log may include details if the shutdown was explicitly requested by another process)?

There are many monitoring services out there (that you can pay for or install yourself) that you could use to monitor a page of your app that needs access to the database(s) and send you an email or SMS when it starts reporting errors. You could also use a local `cron` task running every minute to check that the DB is connectible and if not issues your restart command but please only do this as a *temporary* measure, have it contact you when a restart is needed (and perhaps have it collect other info too), and find the root cause rather than just fixing the symptom as it could be the start of something worse going wrong.